# Why did Chico go to Calvera's camp?

Tags: the-magnificent-seven

In the [Magnificent Seven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054047), there is this scene that Chico goes to Calvera's camp:

[image]

But I do not understand what purpose it served. Why did he go there? He didn't get any information and neither did he kill anyone.

Answer (score 1):

My guess:  Chico was always trying to measure up to the rest, and be an accepted member of the seven -- as an equal or better. He perceived that going to the other camp will accomplish one or more the following:  impress the other six, get bragging rights, get information, or be useful in some way. At any rate, it did impress his girlfriend -- she kissed him after he bragged about it to her. I don't think he went their to kill anyone, because that would have been suicide (something he was not planning to do).